# Order of negative adverbs

Tags: grammaire, pronoms, négation, adverbes, ordre-des-mots

Since we can use multiple negatives in French, is there an order that they should be in when more than one is used, e.g. is it more correct to say "Je ne connais plus personne," or "Je ne connais personne plus," or are they equally correct (with possibly a difference in meaning)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***<s>Plus pas</s>***, ***<s>aucun plus</s>***, ***<s>rien plus</s>***, ***<s>personne plus</s>*** are impossible so only the first form is correct:

> *Je ne connais **plus personne**.*

Same for *rien*:

> *Il n'y a **plus rien**.*

With ***jamais***, both orders are possible but the meaning can be different :

Same meaning:

> ***Plus jamais** ça !* = ***Jamais plus** ça !* The latter is slightly more literary.

Different meanings possible:

> *il n'est **plus jamais** fatigué* ≠ *il n'est **jamais plus** fatigué (que lorsqu'il il ne dort pas assez)*

The second sentence might be ambiguous without context because *plus* can be either positive or négative.

There is the same kind of ambiguity with *plus* and *aucun*:

> ***Plus aucun** ne parle* is unambiguous: no one is speaking any longer.
>
> ***Aucun** ne parle **plus*** is ambiguous, either same meaning as the previous sentence or the opposite: "no one stays mute".

***Guère plus*** and ***plus guère*** have different meanings and again, *plus* is positive when not in the first position:

> *Il n'y a **guère plus** de dix habitants ici.*  There is just over than ten inhabitants here.
>
> *Il n'y a **plus guère** d'habitants ici.* Not much people still live here.

*Plus* is always positive in the sequence *pas plus*:

> *Je n'en veux **pas plus***. I don't want more of it.

Comment: What about other combinations, such as jamais+personne or jamais+rien?

Comment: What do you mean by "slightly more literal"?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Huh, I meant literary...